# Windows 11 Pro laptop does not boot an external SSD with LinuxMint on it

Tags: linux, boot, windows, bios, external-hdd

I have a Windows 11 Pro laptop and I created an `external SSD with LinuxMint 21.2` on it. The external SSD has the full `Grub bootloader` on it as well. I tested the external SSD on two other laptops, one with Ubuntu on it and another with Fedora on it. Both laptops accepted and booted the external SSD without issues.
The Windows 11 Pro laptop finds itself in a never-ending loop of restarting with the message `Reset system` and thus never boots into LinuxMint from the external SSD. I **disabled** both `secure boot` and `fast boot` on my Windows 11 Pro laptop but to no avail. What blocks booting from external SSD on my Windows device? Any additional info you need, please let me know and I give. Thanks.

P.S. after ESC I can go into the boot order and select the external SSD to boot from as a first target. The boot menu even specifies my external SSD as the default first boot target.

Comment: `Any additional info you need` brand/model of the laptop